# How to ssh into an AWS Ec2 instance using bash script (command written in bash script)?

Tags: ssh

I tried sshing using 2 ways:
a) `standard way` by typing ssh command(in the terminal) after launching ec2 instance.
b) `non standard way` - executing a bash script that has a bunch of commands -> sshing to remote server is one of them.

my `script.sh` file :

```
#!/bin/bash
#using aws cli to launch ec2 instance  
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-3490dgf545645 --count 1 --instance-type t4g.small --security-group-ids sg-12344536465 --key-name keypair.pem > output.json

#Wait for the file to be completely written
sleep 5
comm=$(python3 test2.py < output.json)
Instance_ID=$(echo "${comm}")
echo "InstanceID: ${Instance_ID}"

#fetching the ip of the launched instance
command1=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "${Instance_ID}" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress" --output=text);
ip=$(echo "$command1");
echo "IP: ${ip}"
USERNAME="ubuntu"

#trying to ssh now..

echo "Starting connection script...".
ssh -tt -vi keypair.pem ubuntu@"${ip}"
```

When I run `bash -x script.sh` , I get the following output:

## Note : only showing error part

`+ ssh -tt -vi keypair.pem ubuntu@35.154.5.0`
`OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`
`debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\`
`debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/\*.conf matched no files`
`debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for \*`
`debug1: Connecting to 35.154.5.0 \[35.154.5.0\] port 22.`
`debug1: connect to address 35.154.5.0 port 22: Connection refused`
`ssh: connect to host 35.154.5.0 port 22: Connection refused`

Now , if I run the same command on the terminal by typing ,
`ssh -i <keypair.pem> ubuntu@<ip>` , there is **NO port22 connection failed**. I **easily ssh into the instance.**

Why is this happening?
I mean I check that **ssh via port 22 is allowed via firewall(both in terminal and in my security group)**.
It **clearly works when I type the ssh command in the terminal** but
**it doesn't work if I run the ssh command by executing a bash script?**

**I want it to ssh into the ec2 instance when I run the bash script also.** So, whats the issue?

P.S. : If I do ssh into the instance, **I also want to run few commands as well.** Like `sudo apt update`, `ls -al` etc as well. How to do that as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the bash script is executed in a different directory than the terminal. This means that the Key Pair is not available when you run the bash script and so the connection is refused. This matches you error output i can see.

Comment: No, the keypair is fine and is in the right directory. I made sure of that. All the files are in one directory including the keypair.pem file. Because I tried adding full path as well for the keypair.pem in the ssh command in bash script. However, it still gave same error.